# SQL consecutive rows with a fixed time span between each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, window-functions

Good people at StackOverflow,
please be so kind to provide some help...
So what we have here is let's say a table of sort... containing phone calls from customers to some Contact Center (HelpDesk or whatever).

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   DateD  |   DateM   |    Date_Time    |EMPL_ID| PHONE_NO |FIRST_REP |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------
|2016-12-12| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-12 15:55| 16652 | 123456789| First    |
|2016-12-22| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-22 10:42| 18178 | 123456789| First    |
|2016-12-22| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-22 10:54|112981 | 123456789| Repeat   |
|2016-12-22| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-22 10:57| 18179 | 123456789| Repeat   |
|2016-12-23| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-23 12:27| 16653 | 123456789| Repeat   |
|2017-01-05| 2017-01-01| 2017-01-05 15:20| 17896 | 123456789| First    |
|2017-01-11| 2017-01-01| 2017-01-11 15:48| 17909 | 123456789| Repeat   |
|2017-01-18| 2017-01-01| 2017-01-18 10:07| 18175 | 123456789| Repeat   |
|2016-12-03| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-03 20:32| 17745 | 111222333| First    |
|2016-12-21| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-21 18:47| 10982 | 111222333| First    |
|2016-12-22| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-22 15:53| 17820 | 111222333| Repeat   |
|2016-12-28| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-28 13:07| 15976 | 111222333| Repeat   |
|2016-12-29| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-29 21:35| 17896 | 111222333| Repeat   |
|2016-12-29| 2016-12-01| 2016-12-29 21:46| 15498 | 111222333| Repeat   |
|2017-01-02| 2017-01-01| 2017-01-02 16:24| 13117 | 111222333| Repeat   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is figure out, how many calls are repeated, meaning that the customer called again.
Now the tricky part is that the repeated calls is defined as a call that originated from the 'first call' and is being repeated consecutively in the time span of 7 days from each interaction after the first call, so for instance:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   DateD   |    DateM   |    Date_Time     |EMPL_ID|  PHONE_NO |FIRST_REP |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-12 | 2016-12-12 15:55 | 16652 | 123456789 | First    |
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-22 10:42 | 18178 | 123456789 | First    |
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-22 10:54 | 112981| 123456789 | Repeat   |
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-22 10:57 | 18179 | 123456789 | Repeat   |
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-23 | 2016-12-23 12:27 | 16653 | 123456789 | Repeat   |
|2017-01-01 | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 15:20 | 17896 | 123456789 | First    |
|2017-01-01 | 2017-01-11 | 2017-01-11 15:48 | 17909 | 123456789 | Repeat   |
|2017-01-01 | 2017-01-18 | 2017-01-18 10:07 | 18175 | 123456789 | Repeat   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

we've got :
1st row that is a First Call with no repeated calls,
2sd row that is a First Call with 3 repeated calls as every interaction is in the time span of 7 days from each previous one beginning from the First Calls
3rd row that is a First Call with 2 repeated calls just like above.

And now what we want to say is that employee (1st row) with the ID 16652 generated 0 repeated calls but the employee withe the ID 18178 generated on the other hand 3 repeated calls.

Finally it would be great to have some method that would allow to create an output like this:

```
|   DateM   |    DateD   |     Date_Time    |EMP_ID |  PHONE_NO |FIRST_REP | DateM_REP  | DateD_REP  | Date_Time_REP    | EMP_ID_REP | PHONE_NO_REP | FIRST_REP_REP
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-12 | 2016-12-12 15:55 | 16652 | 123456789 |   First  |    null    |    null    |       null       |   null     |    null      | null
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-22 10:42 | 18178 | 123456789 |   First  | 2016-12-01 | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-22 10:54 |   112981   |   123456789  | Repeat
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-22 10:42 | 18178 | 123456789 |   First  | 2016-12-01 | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-22 10:57 |   18179    |   123456789  | Repeat
|2016-12-01 | 2016-12-22 | 2016-12-22 10:42 | 18178 | 123456789 |   First  | 2016-12-01 | 2016-12-23 | 2016-12-23 12:27 |   16653    |   123456789  | Repeat
|2017-01-01 | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 15:20 | 17896 | 123456789 |   First  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-11 | 2017-01-11 15:48 |   17909    |   123456789  | Repeat
|2017-01-01 | 2017-01-05 | 2017-01-05 15:20 | 17896 | 123456789 |   First  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-18 | 2017-01-18 10:07 |   18175    |   123456789  | Repeat
```

Please help, I'm not that good at writing CTE and as I imagine that's a kind problem that has the potential of being solved with CTE.

much oblidged
*LuKI*.

---

edit:

```
CREATE TABLE t_calls
(
[DateM] date,
[DateD] date,
[Date_Time] datetime2(7),
[EMPL_ID] int,
[INTERACTION_ID] numeric(25,0),
[PHONE_NO] numeric(9,0),
[FIRST_REP] varchar(10)
)

Insert Into t_calls

([DateM],[DateD],[Date_Time],[EMPL_ID],[INTERACTION_ID],[PHONE_NO],[FIRST_REP])
Values 
('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-12 00:00:00','2016-12-12 15:55:36',16652,340680165,123456789,'First')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-22 00:00:00','2016-12-22 10:42:45',18178,343736497,123456789,'First')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-22 00:00:00','2016-12-22 10:54:46',112981,343750151,123456789,'Repeat')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-22 00:00:00','2016-12-22 10:57:29',18179,343750151,123456789,'Repeat')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-23 00:00:00','2016-12-23 12:27:56',16653,344071359,123456789,'Repeat')
,('2017-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-05 00:00:00','2017-01-05 15:20:47',17896,347063121,123456789,'First')
,('2017-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-11 00:00:00','2017-01-11 15:48:20',17909,348429965,123456789,'Repeat')
,('2017-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-18 00:00:00','2017-01-18 10:07:45',18175,350243945,123456789,'Repeat')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-03 00:00:00','2016-12-03 20:32:37',17745,338392721,111222333,'First')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-21 00:00:00','2016-12-21 18:47:12',10982,343633967,111222333,'First')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-22 00:00:00','2016-12-22 15:53:59',17820,343885389,111222333,'Repeat')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-28 00:00:00','2016-12-28 13:07:19',15976,344944219,111222333,'Repeat')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-29 00:00:00','2016-12-29 21:35:44',17896,345396945,111222333,'Repeat')
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00','2016-12-29 00:00:00','2016-12-29 21:46:43',15498,345398005,111222333,'Repeat')
,('2017-01-01 00:00:00','2017-01-02 00:00:00','2017-01-02 16:24:12',13117,346045147,111222333,'Repeat')
```

Comment: Could you provide create table and insert values?

Comment: Dunno about CTE's, but I definitely see self joins in your future. Can you provide schema and row constructors?

Comment: @McNets of course man, just edited the question adding some SQL.

Comment: You want to add repeated calls as a new columns, is it?

Comment: This screams for a CLR solution. Write a little function in C# that iterates the calls for each caller, defines if it is within the defined timespan from the last call, thus counts the repeated calls as well as the affected employees. You can create the resultset using a .net DataTable and output it however you like - I prefer sql pipes. Steep learning curve, but worth it.

Comment: @McNets mainly yea, it doesn’t bother me that I get duplicates, cause in the long run I’ll be needing the details on the repeated calls, but for now just to get the hang of it, it would be grate to add a column with repeated calls

Comment: @TheConspiracy no doubt about it, I mean the steep curve although let's stick to pure SQL/TSQL, just for now.

Comment: Would you agree by adding new 7 rows, even if this rows have NULL value?

Comment: @McNets Not sure if I understand correctly. Adding 7 new rows that could be null values? What do you mean? null in this case means no repeated call so where's the 7 null joins getting from?

Comment: I mean, you have defined a time interval of 7 days for every call. I was thinking into build a pivot table [First] [Rep1] [Rep2] .... [Rep6], but obviously most of this columns will be NULL due there is no repetitions.

Comment: Maybe this is not the aim of your question.

Comment: @McNets Ok now I see, but it would had to be a dynamic pivot, as the number of possible repetitions is n until the condition of the 7 days time span from every previous call is false... so I guess it's no use...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question what you want to know for every call, how many calls were repeated within 7 days.

```
SELECT
  a.date_time
  ,a.emp_id
  ,a.phone_no
  ,count(b.phone_no) as repeat_calls  --count any non-null field
  ,min(b.date_time) as first_repeat_call_at
FROM t_calls a
LEFT JOIN t_calls b
  ON a.phone_no = b.phone_no  --same phone
    AND datediff(d, a.date_time, b.date_time) between 0 AND 6 --a repeat comes in today + 6 days
    AND a.date_time < b.date_time  --prevents self join
GROUP BY
  a.date_time
  ,a.emp_id
  ,a.phone_no
```

For any call with 0 repeats, there'll be nothing to join, thus nothing to count so `repeat_calls` = 0 and `first_repeat_call_at` is NULL.